# Mongodb not starting

Tags: mongodb

I installed mongodb a few days ago on my ubuntu machine and I was using it without any problems. Today I had to restart my PC. After that, mongo simply wont start. It says:

```
Wed Sep 12 21:41:21 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10296 dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist, terminating
```

It was working fine just a few hours ago and now it's all screwed up on reboot. I had a lot of important data stored there and I really hope it's not all lost! I need to find that data and run mongodb on that data again. I use pymongo to interract with mongodb.

I just saw the config file and it's storing the data in /var/lib/mongod as the dpath. Now how do I start mongodb specifying this dpath?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start mongodb with the following switch.

```
mongod --dbpath /path/to/mongodb/data
```

Or edit the config file.

```
/etc/mongod.conf
```

Change dbpath to your data directory.

```
dbpath = /path/to/mongodb/data
```

There's a lot more you can add and change in the config file go [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-101) for more details.

Use this command to create your directory tree.

```
mkdir -p data/{db}
```

Comment: Tried the above and it worked but had to navigate to my bin where mongo is installed and use ./mongod instead of just mongod

Comment: is previous data can be recovered?

Answer (score 3):

Use the following command to start mongod:

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

This will pass your system configuration file as an argument to mongod, which (as you saw) will cause it to use the correct path.

Comment: Woaaa this worked for me (on debian), I was always believed /etc/init.d/mongodb start was the same thing, apparently not, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

you need a path to store your database. by default it is `/data/db/`. if it does not exist you have to create it first

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason for this error can be the fact that you are starting the mongodb with user as yourself. If you execute the command with *sudo*, the mongodb should start without error:

```
sudo mongod --dbpath /path/to/mongodb/data
```

One can find the path to mongodb data in file such as /etc/mongod.conf